# For which values of $x$ does the series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^k\cdot 3^2 \cdot x^k}{2^k}$$

I have to find the values of $x$ for which the series converges.
I used the root test,the limit of the absolute value of the kth root of the series must be smaller than 1 and I ended up with $|3x/2|<1 $ which leads to
 $-2/3< x <2/3 $.

and then I put the once  $-2/3 $ and once  $2/3 $ in the original series and tested for convergence and found that for both values the series diverges which means the series only converges in the open interval  $(-2/3,2/3)$.

Am I right or did I miss something?

Comment: Yup, seems about right. Btw, the $3^2$ does not have any significance for whether the series diverges or not.

Comment: What makes you doubt your solution?

Comment: I'm totally new to the topic and I was afraid I missed something in the procedure

Comment: Your procedure is fine :)

Comment: Great thank you all ! :)

Answer (score 1):

The  *[geometric  series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}\qquad\qquad |x|<1
\end{align*}
is convergent for $x\in(-1,1)$.

> OPs example is a geometric series (somewhat in disguise), since
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^k3^2x^k}{2^k}&=3^2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)^k\\
> &=\frac{9}{1-\frac{3}{2}x}\\
> &=\frac{18}{2-3x}
> \end{align*}
>   which is convergent for 
>   \begin{align*}
> &\left|\frac{3}{2}x\right|<1\\
> \end{align*}
>   or equivalently for $x\in\left(-\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right)$.